# launchd: run a daemon periodically while being logged out or when the screen is locked

Tags: macos, launchd

I've looked for ages, but I can't seem to find the right answer that will work. I want to run `launchd` every timestep (e.g. every minute) when I'm logged out or when the screen is locked (I'm happy if I can do it in one or both ways).

What I've done:

- Create a .plist file with a simple command that has text output.
- The .plist has `stdout` and `stderr` output to log files.
- I load it with `sudo launchctl -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/mydaemon.plist
- I create the file via `cp ~/mydaemon.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons`
- Put the energy saver to "never sleep" (including the disks), both on battery and when the power adapter is on.

As long as I'm logged in and have an unlocked screen, it works, the daemon runs.

I've tried both:

- Option key + command key + power button (screen lock)
- Shift + command key + Q (logout)

Comment: Are you sure you ran `launchctl load ...` as root (i.e. with `sudo`)? What you describe sounds like it's running as a launch *agent* (i.e. under your user account) rather than a launch *daemon* (system-wide, independent of user logins)? Try `launchctl list mydaemon` (or whatever its label is), which will list it if it's loaded as an agent; and `sudo launchctl list mydaemon`, which will list it if it's loaded as a daemon.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I noticed there was a `mydaemon.plist` (label) running as a launch agent and a `mydaemon` (another label) running as root. I used `launchctl remove mydaemon.plist` to remove the user version. It may have interfered.

Comment: Yep, I double checked. Everything seems to work now. I didn't see the `sudo launchctl list` trick before. Thanks!